# invalid index to scalar variable as inderError

Tags: python

Why do i get this index error?? The error portion code is as follows :

```py
t1 = time.time()
result = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, steps=steps_epoch)
t2 = time.time()
test_time = t2 - t1
score, accuracy, recall, precision, f1_score = result
f = open("TP_index_blstm.pkl", 'wb')
pickle.dump(result[1], f)
f.close()
#print(type(result[1]))
f_TP = open("./result_analyze/BGRU/TP_filenames.txt", "ab+")
for i in range(len(str(result[1]))):
   TP_index = result[1][i]
   f_TP.write(str(filenames[TP_index]) + '\n')

f_FP = open("./result_analyze/BGRU/FP_filenames.txt", "ab+")
for j in range(len(str(result[2]))):
   FP_index = result[2][j]
   f_FP.write(str(filenames[FP_index]) + '\n')
```

The error it's showing is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bgru.py", line 240, in <module>
    main(traindataSetPath, testdataSetPath, realtestdataSetPath, weightPath, resultPath, 
       batchSize, maxLen, vectorDim, layers, dropout)
  File "bgru.py", line 153, in main
    TP_index = result[1][i]
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

Comment: What is the type of result[1]?

Comment: Check type of `result`. It seems you can't iterate over `result[1]`.

Comment: @theletz <type 'numpy.float64'> is type of result[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you are trying to get an item (by index) from a variable, but this variable is not iterable (list, np.array etc) but a scalar (in this case - int)...

you can`t do - 3[4] or something like this...